# Change a key's allowed actions in GPG?

Tags: gpg

When you `--gen-key` in GPG, you can choose which actions of Sign, Certify, Encrypt, and Authenticate the key will be usable for.

Can these be later *modified* (i.e. obviously a new key can be created if the current one has C, and the old one revoked, but that's not the question) to remove or add actions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keys' allowed usages can be modified, but the `gpg` tool doesn't support it (even in version 2). To change a key's usage, you need to modify `gpg`. The basic idea is detailed in a [thread on the `gnupg-users` mailing list](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2009-May/036485.html): usage information is carried by the self-signature, so you need to change the usage parser to force the value you're interested in, then create a new self-signature on your key, for example by changing your key's expiry date.

Comment: Ouch, I think I'll chalk that up as 'not worth the effort' - thanks though!

Comment: I just noticed that gpg version 2.2.6 has this feature with the `change-usage` subcommand. See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/206766/4350

Answer (score 1):

`change-usage` is the hidden subcommand that will change the allowed action.

```bash
$ gpg --edit-key $KEYID

gpg> change-usage
Changing usage of the primary key.

Possible actions for a RSA key: Sign Certify Encrypt Authenticate 
Current allowed actions: Sign Certify 

   (S) Toggle the sign capability
   (E) Toggle the encrypt capability
   (A) Toggle the authenticate capability
   (Q) Finished

Your selection?
```

Sources -

1. Detailed explanation is given in [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/206766/265564) answer given by **sanmai** to another question.
2. Above link is also mentioned in the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339801/change-a-keys-allowed-actions-in-gpg#comment1262462_339807) given by **David Xia** on the **Stephen Kitt**'s answer to this question.